# What does "Host application code" refer to in this context?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, powershell, embedded

I'm lookin at a job description that lists this as a responsibility:

> Design, develop, and test software for analytical scientific instruments with an emphasis on Host application code

This is a software engineer job in the electronics manufacturing field so i imagine there will be a heavy emphasis on embedded software and drivers as well as electronics test fixturing code.

So what specifically does host application code refer to? I did some googling and found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which suggests it has to do with windows powershell. This would make sense because they also ask for experience with C# or VB.net and visual studio. It looks like they are very windows oriented. But I'm still not entirely sure about what they're looking for.

Comment: You could contact the company and ask them

Comment: My own guess would be it's software to run on general purpose PCs (Hosts) to which the scientific instruments are connected.

Comment: Host software for an instrument can range from a device driver, an API library, a data logger or a soft console.  A soft console could be a CLI interface or a GUI virtualization of the instrument's front panel with enhanced display indicators.  Visit the company's web site to see what existing host SW they have for their product line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On its own it does not mean anything, and almost certainly nothing to do with Powershell.

Whoever wrote it knew what it meant to them, but it has lost all meaning without context.  You simply need to ask the recruiter to elaborate - there is no shame in that, and in fact it would probably be to your credit to show that initiative.

Try:

> "Sounds interesting; can you give me more information?

If I had to guess from the other information you have given, I would imagine that it refers to software running on a PC connected to a number of instruments (perhaps via GPIB, Ethernet, USB, Serial or other interfaced or PCI cards plugged directly into the PC).

Many companies use National Instruments' LabView for this for this sort of application.  I can think of many reasons not to use LabView, but it might be a question for you to bring up in an interview.

Comment: I have a feeling this is exactly what they are referring to. I know that they do a lot of work with labview. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it just means code for the scientific instruments - the instruments will 'host' the embedded code.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that host application software refers to PC-based windows applications that interface to the instruments (via serial, usb, ethernet, or other interface) and are used to configure the instruments, analyze and store data from the instruments, and/or test the instruments.